# What is the relationship between signed negative and positive versions of the same binary integer in decimal?

Tags: math, binary, integer, signed

I want to preface this question by stating that it at first appears that this is a duplicate of several other questions here on SO, but none of the answers to those questions answered my question and thus I am asking it.

What is the relationship between a binary integer interpreted as a positive integer versus that exact same binary integer interpreted as a negative integer in terms of decimal? Let's take for example the integer 5:

5 is 101

-5 is 11111011

11111011 is 251 when interpreted as an unsigned number.

**The question is, what is the decimal relationship between -5 and 251?** Is there a direct relationship aside from the action which occurs in the binary number system? Meaning, is there some rule in decimal that we can directly map any given decimal integer to the decimal integer for which the identical binary integer would be when converted from positive to negative and vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `-5` is not actually `11111011` in binary--that is the binary representation *in eight bits*. If you use a different number of bits you get a different binary representation. For example, if you use 16 bits, as is often done, you get `1111111111111011`, which is `65531`.

This then is the key. In eight bits we consider `2^8` which is `256`. (That caret stands for exponentiation.) We then see that `-5` is represented by `256 - 5`.

So the final answer is this: for a given positive integer `n` that is to be represented in `b` binary bits, the number `-n` is then represented by

```
(2 ^ b) - n
```

At least, if the number of bits `b` is large enough. Is that clear? Much more can be said than that, but you are better off reading more about two's-complement notation in a book or large web page.

Comment: That's assuming [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Two's_complement) representation is used. which probably is the only representation that OP is aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that we work with two complement, we have that a vector of `n` bits:

```
n = <a(n-1), a(n-2), ..., a(2), a(1), a(0)>
```

is interpreted as:

```
n_signed = -[a(n-1) * 2^(n-1)] + sum(i=0, i=n-2) {a(i) * 2^(i)}
```

whereas, treating it as unsigned leads to:

```
n_unsigned = sum(i=0, i=n-1) {a(i) * 2^(i)}
```

Hence the difference is:

```
n_unsigned - n_signed = 2 * [a(n-1) * 2^(n-1)]
```

Hope it helps (and sorry for the poor formatting).